# Branch retroactively

Tags: git, branch

An issue branch contains code for two issues, and I want to split the branch between two commits in order to get one issue per branch. How?

From current:

```
...A           -- master
    \
     B-C-D-E   -- ISSUE-2
```

to

```
...A           -- master
    \
     B-C       -- ISSUE-1
        \
         D-E   -- ISSUE-2
```